# scala count word co-occurrence performance is really low

Tags: python, scala, performance

While I was trying to implement a function to count word co-occurrences in scala, I found my function performance is really low.

The word co-occurrences is:
That's say we have a List[List[Int]] (actually a list of word list),
we will generate a combination for each List[Int],
then we merge all combination into a map and sum the value for each duplicate keys.

Combination:
[0,1,2] -> [((0,1),1),((0,2),1),((1,2),1)]

Merge combination:
[((0,1),1),((0,2),1),((1,2),1)] + [((0,1),1),((0,2),1),((1,2),1)] =
HashMap{(0,1):2,(0,2):2,(1,2):2}

Here's scala version:

```
val arr = Array.range(0, 1000)
val counter = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[(Int, Int), Int](  )
arr.combinations(2).toArray.map{
    row=>
        val key = (row(0), row(1))
        if (!counter.contains(key)) {
            counter(key) = 1
        }
        else {
            counter(key) += 1
        }
}
assert(counter.size == 499500)
```

Scala version 2:

```
val counter = arr.combinations(2).map(x => ((x(0),x(1)), 1)).toArray
.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum)
```

Here's python version:

```
import itertools    
arr = range(0, 1000)
combs = list(itertools.combinations(arr, 2))
counter = dict()
for key in combs:
    try:
        counter[key] += 1
    except KeyError:
        counter[key] = 1
assert len(counter) == 499500
```

Both scala version costs 9 seconds, while python version costs 1 seconds.
I think I am definitely doing something wrong with the code, but I couldn't think of other ways to improve it (I am quite new to scala).

Also, the reason I was using a mutable.HashMap is that I want to reduce memory usage.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could you describe what does `count word co-occrrences` mean? Show example data? Is that simple word count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the combine method from the collection. It creates an iterator which is not efficient. I´ve created another sample which is x10 faster without using the combine:

```
  def time[R](block: => R): R = {
    val t0 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val result = block    // call-by-name
    val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println("Elapsed time: " + (t1 - t0) + "ms")
    result
  }

  val arr = Array.range(0, 1000).toList

  def combinations2[A](input: List[A]): Iterator[(A, A)] =
    input.tails.flatMap(_ match {
      case h :: t => t.iterator.map((h, _))
      case Nil => Iterator.empty
    })

  val counter = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[(Int, Int), Int](  )
  time {
    combinations2(arr).foreach {
      row =>
        val key = row
        if (!counter.contains(key)) {
          counter(key) = 1
        }
        else {
          counter(key) += 1
        }
    }
    assert(counter.size == 499500)
  }
```

check this out

Comment: Thanks! It's amazingly really, and close to python's version, could you be more specific about which part of the original version is the bottleneck, and why?

Comment: It is the combination method from the string. It returns an iterator from you can get the n tuples in a pulling fashion and it is much slower than doing in one time. Perhaps, the developers were afraid due the exponential increase of the resulting collection  and they decided to return a traversable structure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `arr` to a parallel collection. Ideally, to an RDD. So create a spark context, get an RDD from your array as below, then run your operations on that.

```
val arr: RDD[Int] = sparkContext.parallelize(Array.range(0, 1000))
```

You really should look up [some tutorials](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html)

Comment: my questions is just about performance between scala and python, I care about it because I need to implement the function in spark, I know how to use spark in both scala and python, thanks anyway.

Comment: I see. It appeared you wanted a spark solution from your original question and tags :)